# How to remove decimal point from my y axis scale in d3js graph

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, svg, d3.js

Here is link to my d3js graph http://enjalot.com/inlet/4159384/
Problem is that the y axis which shows Year is having values such as 2008.5 and 2009.0 for json data

```
 [{count:200,year:2008},
    {count:240,year:2010},
    {count:290,year:2009}];
```

I want to display Years without any decimal points.How to do it.
Here is my d3js code below

```
    var w = 300,
    h = 300,
    padding = 31,
    p = 10;

var data = [{count:200,year:2008},
    {count:240,year:2010},
    {count:290,year:2009}];

var bar_height = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.count; }) )  // min max of count
    .range([p,h-p]);  // min max of area to plot in


var bar_xpos = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }) )  // min max of year
    .range([p,w-p]);  // min max of area to plot in


var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(bar_xpos)
            .orient("bottom")
            .ticks(5);  //Set rough # of ticks

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(bar_height)
            .orient("left")
            .ticks(5);

var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check out the docs on [d3 value formatting](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting).

If you use `d3.format()` to format your axis, your axis values will look a lot nicer.

```
var formatxAxis = d3.format('.0f');

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(bar_xpos)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickFormat(formatxAxis)
            .ticks(5);
```

`.0f` means:
I want a precision of *0* places after the decimal, and I want values to be *fixed*, i.e. not rounded but truncated.

You'll notice, however, that since you are fixing the precision to 0 places after the decimal, you will have 2009.5 and 2009.0 both being formatted to 2009. This will mean that two axis ticks could have the same value. This error will go away once you have enough data points over more years.

Comment: but some times i have show low data too....any other way so that i wont  have 2 axis ticks with same value in case of low or less data

Comment: @jade Maybe you could handle ticks() conditionally? So look at the minimum and maximum years with d3.min() and d3.max(), then if the range is below, say, 3 years, do a fewer number of ticks, e.g. ticks(3). Otherwise keep it at 5. Does this make sense?

Comment: .1f worked for me instead of .0f